# I want to parse larger decimals to smaller from JSON to Html table

Tags: javascript

'I created table in Html and table show decimals like is shown in my JSON file(remainingstorage and totalstorage).I want to table show only 5 decimals and not like now 12.I try to parse but without success.Can someone help me how to fix this ?'

```
[{"acceptingcontracts":true,"netaddress":"22.169.100.43","remainingstorage":119722213376,"totalstorage":119722213376}]
```

'And my html code'

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("sample.json", function(data) {
    var employee_data = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      employee_data += '<tr>';
      employee_data += '<td>' + value.netaddress + '</td>';
      employee_data += '<td>' + value.totalstorage + '</td>';
      employee_data += '<td>' + value.remainingstorage + '</td>';
      employee_data += '<td>' + value.acceptingcontracts + '</td>';
      employee_data += '</tr>';
    });
    $('#employee_table').append(employee_data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <h1>View</h1>
    <br />

    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="employee_table">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Total storage</th>
        <th>Remaining storage</th>
        <th>View</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"I try to parse but without success"* Please show us what you tried. And please tell us what the expected output should be. Without knowing which 5 of the 12 digits you want to show there isn't much we can do.

Comment: Do you just want to show the first 5 digits of `119722213376`? Look up substring for js

Comment: Do you know the units?  for example remainingstorage: is it in bytes?  then it would be more treadable to convert them to megabytes, gigabytes etc.

Comment: Yes i want to show first 5 digits.Remaining storage and used storage is in bytes.

Comment: What sense would it make to take the first digits of such a value? So when `remainingstorage` decreases from `119722213376` to `89722213376`, you would show `11972` first and then `89722` after - which would suggest the value has _increased_ …? Make no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your Number to string then extract first 5 character fromt it then convert it to Number :

```
Number(value.remainingstorage.toString().substring(0, 5));
```

Comment: I try wont work.Can u explain me litle more please?

Comment: @milos20 if I understand your question you want to display first 5 digits from remainingstorage value that's right?

Comment: Yes.  I try      
parseFloat(((value.remainingstorage[2]) / 100000000000).toFixed[2])  but wont work

Comment: What did you mean by not work is there any error or still return 12 digit ?

Comment: and type what type of value.remainingstorage

Comment: When i parse: (((value.remainingstorage[2]) / 100000000000).toFixed[2]) nothing hapening.(return 12 digit). when i try (((value.remainingstorage[2]) = 100) Then i see given decimals(100 - change in tabele). Only works =

Comment: Does value.remainingstorage type is array?

Comment: Yes. I find solution.Later i will publish answer.